# Block all request from EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ip

I would like to block all requests to my web server originating from `EC2` machines.

Is a **public list of ip address/net** for Ec2 based VMs that I can make use of?

Comment: It might be easier to block requests from *.compute-1.amazonaws.com. Are you doing this because someone is trying to get into your site? If yes, then do report them to Amazon and those folks take this quite seriously.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently this is the [list](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1528)

```
72.44.32.0/19 (72.44.32.0 - 72.44.63.255)
67.202.0.0/18 (67.202.0.0 - 67.202.63.255)
75.101.128.0/17 (75.101.128.0 - 75.101.255.255)
174.129.0.0/16 (174.129.0.0 - 174.129.255.255)
204.236.192.0/18 (204.236.192.0 - 204.236.255.255)
184.73.0.0/16 (184.73.0.0 – 184.73.255.255)
184.72.128.0/17 (184.72.128.0 - 184.72.255.255)
184.72.64.0/18 (184.72.64.0 - 184.72.127.255)
50.16.0.0/15 (50.16.0.0 - 50.17.255.255)
50.19.0.0/16 (50.19.0.0 - 50.19.255.255)
107.20.0.0/14 (107.20.0.0 - 107.23.255.255)
23.20.0.0/14 (23.20.0.0 – 23.23.255.255)
54.242.0.0/15 (54.242.0.0 – 54.243.255.255)
54.234.0.0/15 (54.234.0.0 – 54.235.255.255) 
54.236.0.0/15 (54.236.0.0 – 54.237.255.255) 
50.112.0.0/16 (50.112.0.0 - 50.112.255.255)
54.245.0.0/16 (54.245.0.0 – 54.245.255.255)
204.236.128.0/18 (204.236.128.0 - 204.236.191.255)
184.72.0.0/18 (184.72.0.0 – 184.72.63.255)
50.18.0.0/16 (50.18.0.0 - 50.18.255.255)
184.169.128.0/17 (184.169.128.0 - 184.169.255.255)
54.241.0.0/16 (54.241.0.0 – 54.241.255.255)
79.125.0.0/17 (79.125.0.0 - 79.125.127.255)
46.51.128.0/18 (46.51.128.0 - 46.51.191.255)
46.51.192.0/20 (46.51.192.0 - 46.51.207.255)
46.137.0.0/17 (46.137.0.0 - 46.137.127.255)
46.137.128.0/18 (46.137.128.0 - 46.137.191.255)
176.34.128.0/17 (176.34.128.0 - 176.34.255.255)
176.34.64.0/18 (176.34.64.0 – 176.34.127.255)
54.247.0.0/16 (54.247.0.0 – 54.247.255.255)
54.246.0.0/16 (54.246.0.0 – 54.246.255.255)
175.41.128.0/18 (175.41.128.0 - 175.41.191.255)
122.248.192.0/18 (122.248.192.0 - 122.248.255.255)
46.137.192.0/18 (46.137.192.0 - 46.137.255.255)
46.51.216.0/21 (46.51.216.0 - 46.51.223.255)
54.251.0.0/16 (54.251.0.0 – 54.251.255.255)
175.41.192.0/18 (175.41.192.0 - 175.41.255.255)
46.51.224.0/19 (46.51.224.0 - 46.51.255.255)
176.32.64.0/19 (176.32.64.0 - 176.32.95.255)
103.4.8.0/21 (103.4.8.0 - 103.4.15.255)
176.34.0.0/18 (176.34.0.0 - 176.34.63.255)
54.248.0.0/15 (54.248.0.0 - 54.249.255.255)
177.71.128.0/17 (177.71.128.0 - 177.71.255.255)
54.232.0.0/16 (54.232.0.0 – 54.232.255.255)
```

Comment: you need to update the list as frequently as your needed usage suggests. AWS upates this every few weeks.  it is available in JSON format if that helps.

Comment: the LATEST list in JSON format is at https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json